# LINQ - How to query for a single entity with sub query to populate multiple entities?

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have two tables, "student" table and "scores" table with a foreign key. I have also defined a custom class as follows:

```
public class Student
{ 
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
  public List<int> Scores { get; set; }
}
```

How do I go about writing a LINQ query to retrieve a Student by EmailAddress with all the scores? I have below so far...

```
(from student in myContext.Students
 where student.EmailAddress == emailAddress
 select new Student()
 {
   FirstName = student.FirstName,
   LastName = student.LastName,
   Scores = ???
 }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is the scores variable a list of all the scores or all the scores for that individual student?

Comment: List of scores for that individual student. Scores table has a "StudentID" foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your ef models look like it is hard to be specific, but I would guess something like this should work.

```
(from student in myContext.Students
 where student.EmailAddress == emailAddress
 select new Student()
 {
   FirstName = student.FirstName,
   LastName = student.LastName,
   Scores = student.Scores.Select(studentScore=>studentScore.value)
 }).SingleOrDefault();
```